# close a specific tab in browser window using web driver io

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io, webdriver-io-v4

`browser.close(window handle)` - i tried this but its closing the entire window.

How to close a specific tab from a browser window which has multiple tabs using web-driver io.
I am working on chromedriver.

Answer (score 0):

Before closing the last browser tab please make sure at least one tab exists. Just open some tab before closing.